# Creating a Firestore Database from existing files

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, firebase-storage

I have a few music albums - basically just files in folders - that I want to upload to Firebase Storage.

One would usually run a function after a file has been uploaded to create a Document containing the metadata about the Song but that's where Im stuck.

I can get most infos I need by reading the Tracks ID3 Tags but in a NoSql Database I think im supposed to not only create a Document for the Track but also a Document for each album with an array of all tracks - or at least an array with all track ids.

But when or how do I create the Album Document? Another example is the Album Cover.. I want to save the Url inside the Track Document as well as in the corresponding Album but that means that the Artwork is the first thing I need to upload because I can't add an URL because it doesn't exist yet.

I feel like I have to get this right before I start because updating everything afterwards is a pain.

Is using upload functions really the way to go here or is there really a tool or another way im missing.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) wich is a just a cover for Cloud Storage and it's a obejct managment system not a Database, however I think you are refering to [Firebase Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore).

On firestore since as you mentioned is a NoSQL DB and the schema structure your Db should have, There no correct way to do this and will defitetly depend on each specific use case. However you can take a look at [this docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) where it's expalined how to arquitecture your schema thinking from a  SQL to a NoSQL format.
Among other information the main pointsa are:

- In general, you can treat documents as lightweight JSON records
- You have complete freedom over what fields you put in each document
- After you create the first document in a collection, the collection exists. If you delete all of the documents in a collection, it no longer exists.
- You can use sub collections inside of collections
- Deleting a document does not delete its subcollections!

And finally to have an idea on how to structure the information, you can take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/lukehalley/NoSQL-Spotify) where "NoSQL-Spotify by Luke Halley" explains a NoSQL schema based on spotify so I think it shoudl fit your need or at least give you a starting point.

Comment: thank you very much. these are great resources for my specific case.